# Jenkins configuration with svn for IOS testing

Tags: svn, testing, jenkins, osx-lion

When I configure Jenkins with SVN I get this error:

Unable to access svn+tssh://name@localhost/opt/svnroot/repo/iphone-app/proiject_repertory/ : svn: Cannot find tunnel specification for 'tssh' (show details)
(Maybe you need to enter credential?)

I followed this link:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.javasvn.user/3645

So I did edit ~/.subversion/config.
I tried to 
tssh = ssh -p 2227 -L 1407:10.0.0.190:22 firstname@computer.company.fr
and 
ssh = tssh and tssh = ssh

But it doesn't work, this problem make me crazy for a while now.
Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Stupid question, but where it says "enter credential", did you enter your credentials?

Comment: I already tried it but it doesn't work neither!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with 2 command lines:

Stop Jenkins:
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

Execute Jenkins in /Applications/Jenkins/ to restart the service:
java -jar jenkins.war

Your ssh tunnel must be open.